# How can I prevent accidental deletion of records in QuestDB?

Tags: questdb

I want to expose a QuestDB instance publicly with the web interface so that users and visitors can make queries against the data.
How can I make sure data won't be deleted from this dataset?
Is there a way to prevent malicious queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach that's possible here is to set the server configuration to be readonly via HTTP. This can be set in the `server.conf` file with the following key:

```sh
http.security.readonly=true
```

This will disable commands which modify or delete data. For info on the available keys, see the HTTP [server configuration documentation](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/configuration#http-server)